# creating windows of values from a peak position

Tags: python

I have a series of pulses which I have added a dashed line through the peak position.  The indices of these peaks are in a list;

```
peaks = [13352, 53198, 93037, 133283, 173303, 213749, 253217, 293271, 333690, 373547]
```

[image: pulse plot]

I am trying to integrate over a window of width 10000, centered at each peak position, and create a histogram.  Where I am having trouble is getting these values.

I had initially chosen a set center point of 13000, and taken the center of each pulse to be 13000+40000n, where n = 0,1,2,...  this worked and the code I used is below;

```
pulse_center = np.array([e for i in range(1,40000000,40000) for e in shaped_pulses[i+8000:i+18000]])
```

Although when trying to adjust this such that the window is centered at the peak position, according to my list 'peaks' it does not work.  The code I am trying is below;

```
for j in peaks:  # creating 10,000 width windows to integrate over the pulse peaks 
    pulse_centers = np.array([e for i in range(1,40000000,40000) for e in shaped_pulses[i+(j-5000):i+(j+5000)]])
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: This code returns the window for only the first pulse.  It is not iterating through the values in peaks.